# How to call a function and return variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

please can someone help me understand how to write a beginner function in Python?

The specific thing I want to do is...

I have 2 variables, and I want to apply the same function to both of them, and end up with 2 new things called separate things, how do I best do that?

```
a = "abc"
b = "def"

def foo(input):
    thing = len(input)
    return()
```

how do I call foo to end up with distinctly named outputs, based on the variable?

```
alen = 3
blen = 3
```

Comment: instead of return() set return thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs to actually return a value. Keep in mind that `return` isn't a function that you call (like `return()`) but a statement followed by the thing that you're returning. So in your case, your function should end with `return thing`.

How to actually use the function is simple:

```
a = "abc"
alen = foo(a)
```

Comment: Thanks muchly, i'll delete it as its too basic to be useful for anyone else?

Comment: @FieldsOfAsh Probably. Best for now to accept the answer if it helped you and close it quickly.